# Nested multi-line lambda Function as parameter for LINQ Select is causing an error

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to use a nested multi-line lambda `Function` in VB.NET and am getting an error.  Here's what my code looks like:

```
cartItems = cartItems.Select(Function(ci) New With {.CartItem = ci, .Discount = discountItems.FirstOrDefault(Function(di) di.SKU = ci.SKU)}) 
.Select(Function(k)
            If k.Discount Is Not Nothing Then
                k.CartItem.Discount = minNumberOfItemsDiscounted * k.Discount.DiscountAmount
            End If
            Return k.CartItem
        End Function)
```

And here's the long error message:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Integer, TResult)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
    Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.
    Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of <anonymous type>, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error. C:\_Dev Projects\CMS2000\Components\NET\HBCatalogPromo\CatalogPromotion\CatalogPromotion.ConsoleTest\Module1.vb 88  21  CatalogPromotion.ConsoleTest
```

It feels like I have something wrong with my syntax because I've fixed other lines by collapsing in line `Functions` on to one line when possible.  However, I can't do that in this case.

Comment: Can you paste in the ENTIRE statement?  The error appears to be caused by what is "before" the first .Select...

Comment: I don't think you really want Select -- or rather **what are you doing with side-effects in it?!?!?**

Comment: @Reed I pasted in the first line.  The reason I had left it out was because by itself, the first line does not throw an error.

Comment: Please post more context. What items are in the cartItems and discountItems lists, and what fields do they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is throwing because the compiler can't determine the appropriate type due to your usage of a anonymous type.

That being said, it's a bad idea, in general, to use Select() to run code that causes a side effect, which you're doing in this case.

I would, personally, abandon doing this in a single LINQ statement, in this instance.  The LINQ is, in my opinion, causing this to be more complex than it ought to be.  My preference, in a case like this, would be to make a single function that does your logic, and returns an appropriate, filled in (known, non-anonymous type).  You could then just refactor your LINQ statement into a single Select which returns your known type.

This would avoid the potential side effects, since you could construct a new instance of the type in the method, and simplify the code (including making it much more easily testable, by refactoring the logic into a separate method that worked on a single "instance").

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  If the intent is to change data, separate that step from the LINQ query.  That way you don't get a side effect from the process.

Comment: @Ben: Exactly.  It also means the method that converts the data can work on a single element, and be **testable**.  Putting it into a LINQ statement muddles the issue - since you're "querying" while modifying.  It can work, but it has the same smell as trying to modify a collection while iterating over it in a foreach statement, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[Reactive Extension .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)'s Do() extension method might be a good candidate if you expecting only side-effect. After that, you can use Select() projection method as normal.